# Simplify: $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial(\ln x)\partial(\ln y)}$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives, vectors, partial-derivative

Given a smooth function $f(x,y)$, find $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial(\ln x)\partial(\ln y)}$.

---

The solution is not hard

$$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial(\ln x)\partial(\ln y)}=\partial_{\ln x}\frac{\partial f}{1/y\partial y}$$

$$=\partial_{\ln x}(yf_y)$$
$$=y\partial_{\ln x}(f_y)+f_y\frac{\partial y}{\partial {\ln x}}$$
$$=yx\partial_xf_y-f_y\frac{f_x}{1/xf_y}$$
$$=xyf_{xy}-xf_x$$

Similarly, we can find:

$$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial(\ln y)\partial(\ln x)}=xyf_{xy}-yf_y$$

Obviously $$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial(\ln y)\partial(\ln x)}=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial(\ln x)\partial(\ln y)}$$

So

$$xf_x=yf_y$$

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $\frac{\partial y }{\partial \ln x} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial \ln y} = 0$ ($y$ is treated as a constant when differentiating WRT $x$ and vice versa). So the answer in both cases is just $xyf_{xy}$.